# How do i send a PUT request in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle, put

I am trying to update data through sending an http put request to ServiceDesk plus api. When using the console that comes with the system, it works well but when I try to send a request to the same api from Laravel it does not work.

request from the console below

[image]

I am trying to send a request to the same url using the code below.

```
 private function openTicket($notification)
 {
    $data = json_encode(['input_data' => ['request' => ['subject' => $notification->subject,
            'description' => $notification->description,
            'status' => ['name' => 'Open']]]]);


    $request_id = $notification->request_id;
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'technician_key' => 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ])->put('http://localhost:8082/api/v3/requests/' . $request_id, $data);

     dd($response);
    }
```

and im getting an error **400 bad request**.

[image]

Comment: What does `dd($response->body());` output?

Comment: Maybe you need to send any headers or the like

Comment: Let me try @shaedrich, wait

Comment: @shaedrich this is the output `"{"response_status":{"status_code":4000,"messages":[{"status_code":4001,"field":"input_data","type":"failed","message":"Value not provided"}],"status":"failed"}}"`

Comment: Seems like you didn't provide a required value. Do you have any idea, which?

Comment: It says input_data but it is there on the request already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234058/discussion-between-kgori-dev-and-shaedrich).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution and it is as follows,

```
private function openTicket($notification): bool
    {
        $data = json_encode(['request' => ['subject' => $notification->subject,
            'description' => $notification->description,
            'status' => ['name' => 'Open']]]);

        $request_id = $notification->request_id;
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'technician_key' => 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        //added asForm() before put
        ])->asForm()->put('http://localhost:8082/api/v3/requests/' . $request_id, [
            'input_data' => $data
        ]);
      
        if ($response->status() == 200) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I added asForm() before the put function. This is because asForm() indicates that the request contains form parameters. I also modified the $data object from

```
$data = json_encode(['input_data' => ['request' => ['subject' => $notification->subject,
            'description' => $notification->description,
            'status' => ['name' => 'Open']]]]);
```

to

```
$data = json_encode(['request' => ['subject' => $notification->subject,
            'description' => $notification->description,
            'status' => ['name' => 'Open']]]);
```

Then it worked as i had expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do `json_encode`, laravel `Http` module will automatically do it for you. I think your data is json_encoded twice right now.

```
$data = [
  'input_data' => [
    'request' => [
      'subject' => $notification->subject,
      'description' => $notification->description,
      'status' => ['name' => 'Open']
    ]
  ]
]);


    $request_id = $notification->request_id;
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'technician_key' => 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ])->put('http://localhost:8082/api/v3/requests/' . $request_id, $data);

     dd($response);
```

---

I just noticed. From the documentation you provided in the screenshot, the `input_data` nesting level in the array should not exist

```
$data = [
  'request' => [
    'subject' => $notification->subject,
    'description' => $notification->description,
    'status' => ['name' => 'Open']
  ]
]);
```

Comment: It is not working, tried following that and still gives the same error

Comment: I just noticed the documentation, the `input_data` nested level is useless. I updated my answer

Comment: I managed to solve it, thank you @gbalduzzi